# Get the content of a text box, create a .txt file from it and store it in to the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file

I have created a form that the users are required to insert a name at the first text field and write something on the second one(some information). 
Here is my code for my form:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='insert.php?selected=$openFolder&id=$student'>
       Information name:</br> <input name='infoName' type='text' /><br />
       Information:<br />
       <textarea name='text' rows='15' cols='60'>
       </textarea><br />
       <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Information'/>
       </form>";
```

So far so good.

Now when the form is submitted i need to create a file with:

Filename --> the name that the user is inserting in the 'infoName' text field

And then to insert the content of the 'text' text field into this file and store the whole file into my database.

Here is my code for that:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))    
{    
//Make sure that a file name is given by the user    
if (!$_POST['infoName'])    
{    
echo "<center><font color='red'>You must complete the Information name field</font></center>";            
}     
else    
 {    
$informationName = $_POST['infoName'];
$informationContent = $_POST['text'];

$newFile = fopen($informationName,"w");         
$content = fwrite($newFile,$informationContent  . "\n");
$content = addslashes($content);        
fclose($newFile);

$theSize = filesize($informationName);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())    
{    
  $informationName = addslashes($informationName);    
}    

$query = "INSERT INTO $openFolder (studentID, name, size, type, content, insertedBy ) ".
   "VALUES ('$student','$informationName', '$theSize', 'txt', '$content', '$username')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');                                      


}    
}
```

My problems:
1) The file is created right and is stored in my database but with not the right content in it. For some reason im not inserting right the text into the file...

2) Excepted the file that is stored in my database, one more file is created in my directories and i don't want that to happen.

Help me please. Feel free to make any changes to my code!
Please tell me what im doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I see the cause is the statement `$content = addslashes($content);`. [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) returns count of bytes written and not the data itself as it.
The correct statement should be `$informationContent = addslashes($informationContent);` and should be within your `if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())` condition. Also change your query and replace variables as suggested.

Also make sure you check the return value of fwrite. If nothing got written ( === FALSE), don't proceed further and report error. Many bugs are harder to debug (like this case) just cause we often write assumption programming. :)